# Function Composition - Haskell

Tags: haskell, currying, function-composition, partial-application

again another question generated by my attempts at the Project Euler questions ([follow on from a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344196/project-euler-8-haskell)). I'm having trouble understanding the following line:

```
print (maximum (map (product . take 13) (tails number)))
```

Specifically

```
map (product . take 13) (tails number)
```

The type signature for the first argument of map from ghci is  [c] -> c:

```
ghci> :t (product . take 13)
(product . take 13) :: Num c => [c] -> c
```

The type signature for `map (product . take 13)` from ghci is [[b]] -> [b]:

```
ghci> :t map (product . take 13)
map (product . take 13) :: Num b => [[b]] -> [b]
```

Am I right in saying that as the first argument of map should be a function, [[b]] is not referring to a list of lists, but rather to a list of (partially applied) functions generated by `(product . take 13)`, with the second argument for the partial functions coming from  `(tails number)`?

Comment: no - `product . take 13` is already a function (here from a list of some `c` (where `c` is an instance of `Num` because we want to multiply `c`s) to `c`) you should read it from right-to-left: first you take all *final-segments* list of numbers (see [`tails`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails)), then you multiply the numbers (but only the first 13) in there for each of these segments (`map (product . take 13)`), then you take the maximum of these products (remember one for each segment) and finally you print it

Comment: when some code is hard to understand, simplify! `Prelude Data.List> map (take 4) (tails [1..5])` ==> `[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5],[4,5],[5],[]]`. This is faulty (only 2 subsequences, of length 4,  should be considered here); check out my recent answer to your previous question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a point-free version:

```
euler8 :: (Ord c, Num c) => [c] -> c
euler8 = maximum . map (product . take 13) . tails
```

let's make this a bit more obvious:

```
euler8' numbers = 
  let segments = tails numbers
      groups   = map (take 13) segments -- only take up to 13 numbers from each segment
      products = map product groups
      max      = maximum products
  in max
```

so as you can see - it first gets the *final-segments* of the numbers-list (this is a list again)

then it uses `map` to get the product for each of these segments (again a list)

and finaly it searches for the `maximum` of those products and returns it

PS: I striped the `print` in both versions - I think the `IO` will just complicate matters and it's not really important ... you can always print it out afterwards ;)

Comment: we can take it further apart, as `map (f . g) == map f . map g`.

Comment: yes that is true - but I think the `take 13` part is just a precaution  against long runtimes or something (have to admit I did not google the problem itself) and IMO we could just stip it to simplify understanding too

Comment: but ok - let's do it for now

Comment: and now it is plain, "only take up to 13 numbers" is wrong for the job: the problem talks of subsequences of length 13, not "up to 13". it's not your error, of course. :)

Comment: I know I was a bit quick in my judgment there ... sadyl my edit and your comments are concurrent ;)

Comment: you weren't wrong at all; the code the OP refers to is wrong. :)

Comment: Hm the `take 13` is wrong in principle but will work for the project example because the short tails won't give a maximum, especially as the last digit is zero. It would however break for 11111111111110999999999999, for example.

Comment: yeah - but the question was more to the types not so much the euler-question so I choose to let it as it is ... but thanks

Comment: @WillNess Oh hah, I hadn't seen your answer, so I came up with essentially the same example independently.

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right in saying that as the first argument of map should be a
>   function ?

Yes, the first argument of `map` should be a function. See it's type:

```
λ> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

It takes a function of type `(a -> b)`. But in your case the `a -> b` refers to `(product . take 13)`:

```
λ> :t (product . take 13)
(product . take 13) :: Num a => [a] -> a
```

So, this is a function which takes a list of elements `[a]` and produces a single value of type `a` from it. You can actually test this in ghci:

```
λ> (product . take 14) [1,2,3]
6
```

For simplicity, it gets applied like this:

```
(\x -> product (take 14 x)) [1,2,3]
```

> the second argument for the partial functions coming from (tails number)?

`tails` is a normal function with the type:

```
λ> :t tails
tails :: [a] -> [[a]]
```

So, this function accepts a list of element and gives you a list of list of elements. You can play with this around in ghci:

```
λ> tails [1,2]
[[1,2],[2],[]]
```

I hope that makes it clear.