# Project Euler 8 - I don't understand it

Tags: haskell

I looked up for a solution in Haskell for the 8th Euler problem, but I don't quite understand it.

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char

euler_8 = do
   str <- readFile "number.txt"
   print . maximum . map product
         . foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat [])
         . take 13 . tails . map (fromIntegral . digitToInt)
         . concat . lines $ str
```

[Here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Euler_problems/1_to_10#Problem_8) is the link for the solution and [here](https://projecteuler.net/problem=8) you can find the task.

Could anyone explain me the solution one by one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Reading the data

`readFile` reads the file `"number.txt"`. If we put a small 16 digit number in a file called `number.txt`

```
7316
9698
8586
1254
```

Runing

```
euler_8 = do
   str <- readFile "number.txt"
   print $ str
```

Results in

```
"7316\n9698\n8586\n1254"
```

This string has extra newline characters in it. To remove them, the author splits the string into `lines`.

```
euler_8 = do
   str <- readFile "number.txt"
   print . lines $ str
```

The result no longer has any `'\n'` characters, but is a list of strings.

```
["7316","9698","8586","1254"]
```

To turn this into a single string, the strings are `concat`enated together.

```
euler_8 = do
   str <- readFile "number.txt"
   print . concat . lines $ str
```

The concatenated string is a list of characters instead of a list of numbers

```
"7316969885861254"
```

Each character is converted into an `Int` by `digitToInt` then converted into an `Integer` by `fromInteger`. On 32 bit hardware using a full-sized `Integer` is important since the product of 13 digits could be larger than `2^31-1`. This conversion is `map`ped onto each item in the list.

```
euler_8 = do
   str <- readFile "number.txt"
   print . map (fromIntegral . digitToInt)
         . concat . lines $ str
```

The resulting list is full of `Integer`s.

```
[7,3,1,6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4]
```

#### Subsequences

The author's next goal is to find all of the 13 digit runs in this list of integers. `tails` returns all of the sublists of a list, starting at any position and running till the end of the list.

```
euler_8 = do
   str <- readFile "number.txt"
   print . tails
         . map (fromIntegral . digitToInt)
         . concat . lines $ str
```

This results in 17 lists for our 16 digit example. (I've added formatting)

```
[
  [7,3,1,6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
    [3,1,6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
      [1,6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
        [6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
          [9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
            [6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
              [9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
                [8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
                  [8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
                    [5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
                      [8,6,1,2,5,4],
                        [6,1,2,5,4],
                          [1,2,5,4],
                            [2,5,4],
                              [5,4],
                                [4],
                                 []
]
```

The author is going to pull a trick where we rearrange these lists to read off 13 digit long sub lists. If we look at these lists left-aligned instead of right-aligned we can see the sub sequences running down each column.

```
[
  [7,3,1,6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [3,1,6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [1,6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [6,1,2,5,4],
  [1,2,5,4],
  [2,5,4],
  [5,4],
  [4],
  []
]
```

We only want these columns to be 13 digits long, so we only want to `take` the first `13` rows.

```
[
  [7,3,1,6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [3,1,6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [1,6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [5,8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [8,6,1,2,5,4],
  [6,1,2,5,4],
  [1,2,5,4]
]
```

`foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat [])` transposes a list of lists (explaining it belongs to perhaps [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24609264/414413)). It discards the parts of the rows longer than the shortest row.

```
euler_8 = do
   str <- readFile "number.txt"
   print . foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat [])
         . take 13 . tails
         . map (fromIntegral . digitToInt)
         . concat . lines $ str
```

We are now reading the sub-sequences across the lists as usual

```
[
  [7,3,1,6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1],
  [3,1,6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2],
  [1,6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5],
  [6,9,6,9,8,8,5,8,6,1,2,5,4]
]
```

#### The problem

We find the `product` of each of the sub-sequences by `map`ping `product` on to them.

```
euler_8 = do
   str <- readFile "number.txt"
   print . map product
         . foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat [])
         . take 13 . tails
         . map (fromIntegral . digitToInt)
         . concat . lines $ str
```

This reduces the lists to a single number each

```
[940584960,268738560,447897600,1791590400]
```

From which we must find the `maximum`.

```
euler_8 = do
   str <- readFile "number.txt"
   print . maximum . map product
         . foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat [])
         . take 13 . tails
         . map (fromIntegral . digitToInt)
         . concat . lines $ str
```

The answer is

> 1791590400

Comment: But isn't repeat problematic, because it creates an infinite list?

Comment: @user2965601 `zipWith`, as also `zip`, stops when the shortest of its argument lists ends. So using the infinite list ensures that whatever the length of the shortest list, it will be processed in full. The rest of `[]`s in the infinite list will be ignored, because of Haskell's lazyness. Of course the length can be calculated (1000-13, +-1) and the lists evened out with `drop`, but using this trick is nice, for it takes care of the ends alignment automagically, without calculations. Note that `foldr f [a,b,c,...,n] z == f a (f b (f c ...(f n z) ... ))`.

Comment: @user2965601 ... lists evened out ... with `take`, of course, not `drop`.

Comment: Could the `foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat [])` line be replaced with the `transpose` function from `Data.List` since it is already being imported anyway?

Comment: With regards to my above comment, it appears that `transpose` could possibly yield a different answer, though it is unlikely. Unlike `zipWith` it does not automagically drop the parts of a given row longer than the shortest row. E.g. `transpose [[1,2],[3],[4]]` yields `[[1,3,4],[2]]` where as the `foldr` method would yield `[[1,3,4]]`. This means that `transpose` leaves some additional lists with less than 13 items in the mix. Usually, these lists would not have a larger product, however it's possible e.g. if a list had mainly low products and there were an island of 9s surrounded by 0s.

Comment: A simple example of the above would be the list [[1],[1],[1,9]]. Using the transpose method, the largest product is 9 but the foldr method would give you 1.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not familiar with the functions used, the first thing you should do is examine the types of each function. Since this is function composition, you apply from inside out (i.e. operations occur right to left, bottom to top when reading). We can walk through this line by line.

Starting from the last line, we'll first examine the types.

```
:t str
str :: String -- This is your input
:t lines
lines :: String -> [String] -- Turn a string into an array of strings splitting on new line
:t concat
concat :: [[a]] -> [a] -- Merge a list of lists into a single list (hint: type String = [Char])
```

Since `type String = [Char]` (so `[String]` is equivalent to `[[Char]]`), this line is converting the multi-line number into a single array of number characters. More precisely, it first creates an array of strings based on the full string. That is, one string per new line. It then merges all of these lines (now containing only number characters) into a single array of characters (or a single `String`).

The next line takes this new String as input. Again, let's observe the types:

```
:t digitToInt
digitToInt :: Char -> Int -- Convert a digit char to an int
:t fromIntegral
fromIntegral :: (Num b, Integral a) => a -> b -- Convert integral to num type
:t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b] -- Perform a function on each element of the array
:t tails
tails :: [a] -> [[a]] -- Returns all final segments of input (see: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails)
:t take
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a] -- Return the first n values of the list
```

If we apply these operations to our string current input, the first thing that happens is we map the composed function of `(fromIntegral . digitToInt)` over each character in our string. What this does is turn our string of digits into a list of number types. **EDIT** As pointed out below in the comments, the `fromIntegral` in this example is to prevent overflow on 32-bit integer types. Now that we have converted our string into actual numeric types, we start by running tails on this result. Since (by the problem statement) all values must be adjacent and we know that all of the integers are non-negative (by virtue of being places of a larger number), we take only the first 13 elements since we want to ensure our multiplication is groupings of 13 consecutive elements. How this works is difficult to understand without considering the next line.

So, let's do a quick experiment. After converting our string into numeric types, we now have a big list of lists. This is actually kind of hard to think about what we actually have here. For sake of understanding, the contents of the list are not very important. What is important is its size. So let's take a look at an artificial example:

```
(map length . take 13 . tails) [1..1000]
[1000,999,998,997,996,995,994,993,992,991,990,989,988]
```

You can see what we have here is a big list of 13 elements. Each element is a list of size 1000 (i.e. the full dataset) down to 988 in descending order. So this is what we currently have for input into the next line which is, arguably, the most difficult-- yet most important-- line to understand. Why understanding this is important should become clear as we walk through the next line.

```
:t foldr
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b -- Combine values into a single value
:t zipWith
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c] -- Generalization of zip
:t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a] -- Cons operator. Add element to list
:t repeat
repeat :: a -> [a] -- Infinite list containing specified value
```

Remember how I mentioned we had a list of 13 elements before (of varying-sized lists)? This is important now. The line is going to iterate over that list and apply `(zipWith (:))` to it. The `(repeat [])` is such that each time `zipWith` is called on a subsequence, it starts with an empty list as its base. This allows us to construct a list of lists containing our adjacent subsequences of length 13.

Finally, we get to the last line which is pretty easy. That said, we should still be mindful of our types

```
:t product
product :: Num a => [a] -> a -- Multiply all elements of a list together and return result
:t maximum
maximum :: Ord a => [a] -> a -- Return maximum element in the list
```

The first thing we do is map the `product` function over each subsequence. When this has completed we end up with a list of numeric types (hey, we finally don't have a list of lists anymore!). These values are the products of each subsequence. Finally, we apply the `maximum` function which returns only the largest element in the list.

Comment: The `fromIntegral` is not superfluous, it prevents `Int` overflow on 32-bit systems. I added it in response to [a previous SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344196/project-euler-8-haskell). I vaguely recall someone else "cleaned it up" later, though. I'm not sure though, because someone also broke diffs on the Haskell wiki...

Comment: Ah, thanks for pointing this out! :) I have corrected the post.

Comment: BTW I just realized that the "cleaned up" version is of course @WillNess's corrected version from his answer to the same SO question.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I found out later what the `foldr` expression was for. (See comments bellow my answer).

I think that this could be expressed in different way - You can simply add a guard at the end of the list.

My verbose version of that solution would be:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Char

euler_8 = do
    let len  = 13
    let str1 = "123456789\n123456789"
    -- Join lines 
    let str2 = concat (lines str1)
    -- Transform the list of characters into a list of numbers
    let lst1 = map (fromIntegral . digitToInt) str2
    -- EDIT: Add a guard at the end of list
    let lst2 = lst1 ++ [-1]
    -- Get all tails of the list of digits
    let lst3 = tails lst2
    -- Get first 13 digits from each tail
    let lst4 = map (take len) lst3
    -- Get a list of products
    let prod = map product lst4
    -- Find max product
    let m    = maximum prod
    print m
```

Comment: Nice explanation. Per your question at the beginning of your answer, `map (take 13)` will result in some lists shorter than length 13, whereas `foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat []) . take 13` won't. Though idiomatically this would probably be spelled `transpose . take 13` instead.

Comment: If finding consecutive digits that minimized the product, the difference between `map (take 13)` and `foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat []) . take 13` would be very important.

Comment: @DanielWagner `transpose . take 13` also results in some lists shorter than length 13.

Comment: @Cirdec It could matter for the maximum too, if we had something like `0999999999999` at the end of the input.

Comment: I have edited my answer to make the solution correct.

Comment: @Cirdec exactly! `transpose` could conceivably be defined either way, but `zip` is `zip`, so the meaning is clear.

Comment: @Cirdec You're absolutely right, `transpose` is not a correct respelling of `foldr (zipWith (:)) (repeat [])`.